# How to grab MySQL data into a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I form a multidimensional array using MySQL data? I'm using this code right now:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $music[$row['artist']][$row['title']][$row['id']][$row['category_id']] = $row['key'];
}
```

And I think it would be much easier to use a multi-dimensional array to store my data (artist array => title array => id, category_id, key) but I have no idea how to form one using data from a database. I've googled and can only find examples of static/local data multidimensional arrays, which is no good to me.

I'd also like to know how to output multidimensional data in php for real-world use. Would I use loops? Or would there be an another way?

And I'd just like to say thanks for all the help I've gotten so far at stackoverflow, it's saved me a great deal of headaches!

Comment: Just note that doing this can be kind of expensive to do every time. It's probably better to structure your code so that all the work you need to get done on your data happens inside the loop without needing to construct this extra array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$music = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ( !isset($music[$row['artist']] ) {
        $music[$row['artist']] = array()
        }
    $music[$row['artist']][$row['title']]=array('id'=>$row['id'],'category_id'=>$row['category_id'],'key'=>$row['key'];
    }
```

or more simply if memory requirement is not terribly important (I do this mostly):

```
$music = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if ( !isset($music[$row['artist']] ) {
        $music[$row['artist']] = array()
        }
    $music[$row['artist']][$row['title']]=$row;
    }
```

Using two for-as loops would work -- assuming you want to display a tree of artists, than subtrees of titles:

```
foreach ( $music as $artist => $titles ) {
    foreach ( $titles as $title => $details ) {
        // do stuff, $details contains all the details for the specific $artist and $title
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $music = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach($row as $k => $v)
    {
        $music[$key][] = $v;
    }
}

print_r($music);
```